# Node Group sockets that adapt to attached wire data type?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Is it possible to generate a node group whose input node datatypes depend on the type of input that is wired to them?  i.e. rather than forcing the given input node to be of a fixed type (i.e. float) I would also like my node group to handle it as a vector.  I know some of the built-in nodes do this.  i.e. `attribute statistic` will change the "Attribute" input between a float or a vector depending on the parameter selection in the node itself.

I would prefer that the socket type changes based on what is wired to it, but would settle for a similar setup as `attribute statistic` where I have to select the socket type.

My goal is to create a set of utilities that are as flexible as possible - i.e. to convert from inches to metric, I would like to have one conversion node group that I use everywhere, both on floats and vectors.

[image] [image]

Comment: Both [exposing dropdowns](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/enum-sockets-proposal/21318) as inputs and [dynamic typed sockets](https://developer.blender.org/T95448) are in design phase. For now, I don't think there is a better way than preparing all possible setups and `Switch`ing between them.

Comment: Internally these are separate sockets, and they are dynamically hidden / shown when you switch the input type. That is why the node links disappear when you switch the type. For example the Switch node has dozens of input sockets, but only 3 of them are shown at any given time. You can theoretically add new nodes with the help of the Python API, and use custom logic. The animation nodes and Sverchok addons do it.